# Knockoutjs click binding on parent prevents submit of child form

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-click-event

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZGv5/2/).  There is a `<div>` with a click binding.  This div has a child form.  Clicking the submit button on the child form fires the parent click event, and does not submit the form.

How can I restore the ability to submit this form?  In my real-life application, I also have a file field in the form, which does nothing when it is clicked.  I mention that just to avoid any answers like:

```
$('#myForm input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you are not looking for something simple like this: http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/ssZQg/1/ as a workaround???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `return true` from your `doSomething` method, then it will allow the default action to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, I see that's in the documentation here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_click_action.  I read that page twice through, must have just stared right through it!

Comment: Thanks. Found out that KO was the culprit after commenting out large swathes of code :-|